# How to split a list based on a condition and while keeping the split value in the sublist?

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a way to split a list into sublists based on a pattern while keeping the matching value in the sublist?

For instance, we have the following list:

```
{a, x, x, a, b, y, a, c, z}
```

and we want to produce the following (split on `a`):

```
{{a, x, x}, {a, b, y}, {a, c, z}}
```

then how might we achieve this? In other words, we want to split a list based on a condition while keeping the condition in the sublist. So far I've tried SequenceSplit which produces the list without `a` (in this case). However, I'm having trouble formulating the pattern which will keep the split value in the sublist.

Thanks very much for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
alist = {a, x, x, a, b, y, a, c, z}

Split[alist, UnsameQ[#2, a] &]
```

> `{{a, x, x}, {a, b, y}, {a, c, z}}`

Answer (score 7):

```
SequenceCases[{a, x, x, a, b, y, a, c, z}, {a, Except[a] ..}]
```

> `{{a, x, x}, {a, b, y}, {a, c, z}}`